# Axios error - form-data does not provide an export named default

Tags: vue.js, axios, form-data

I used Axios in one of my Vue Package components and when I import my component, I got this error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/form-data/lib/browser.js?v=93b68a84' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

"axios": "^1.1.2"

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
  timeout: 100000,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
});

export default instance;
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing `export default instance` in this code

Comment: I have export default instance, just not write here, error is about form-data

Comment: Please share the relevant code

Comment: I added my code, just import this file and I got the error

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: I just use import axios from "axios" without no use and got error. its not related to my code

Comment: It's not related to axios for me, you do something with formData somewhere and try to import some variable that is not export inside the lib.

Comment: I did not use formData on my project, added a photo